# web Crystal report working fine on development machine but not on testing server

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a .Net 3.5 web application in which I open few crystal reports.

It works fine in my development environment but when I copy the code onto my testing server it doesn't display the report just a blank page.

Code of the page is below

HTML

```
 <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="CrystalReport.aspx.vb"
    Inherits="Woodland.CrystalReport" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Report</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="rv1" runat="server" Visible="true" AutoDataBind="false" />
    </form>
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
    </CR:CrystalReportSource>
</body>
</html>
```

CodeBehind

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.Web
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Partial Public Class CrystalReport
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Try

            Dim CR As New ReportDocument
            Dim paramList As New List(Of ParameterBO)
            paramList = Session("ReportParams")
            Dim path As String = Server.MapPath(Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("CrystalReportPath").ToString() & Session("ReportName").ToString())

            CR.Load(path)

            For Each param As ParameterBO In paramList
                If Not param.ParameterValue = "" Then
                    CR.SetParameterValue(param.ParameterName, "'" & param.ParameterValue & "'")
                Else
                    CR.SetParameterValue(param.ParameterName, "null")

                End If
            Next
            CR.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection(Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Server").ToString(), Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("DatabaseName").ToString(), Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("UserName").ToString(), Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Password").ToString())
            Me.rv1.ReportSource = CR

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Not sure how you people can figure out the problem  but any pointers would be really appreciated. I can confirm I have installed .net and crystal on my testing server as well

Also I have tried running the report directly on my testing server and its working fine.

--net 3.5
--Crystal report 2008

Answer (score 0):

1. My first guess is a database permissions issue. Does the Testing server have the same database rights as the Dev server?
2. The blank report can mean that Crystal is indeed pulling the data succesfully, but all the tables are empty.  Is the datasource for the Testing Server being updated?